# Is it possible to reveal element without overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

Is it possible to create [this kind](http://jsfiddle.net/vvwc27u7/) of interface but without `overflow:hidden` on container (`.bar`).

I can not use `overflow:hidden` because in `.row-1` and `.row-2` I have some dropdown elements which are obviously bigger than .row. So if I use `overflow:hidden` those dropdowns would be cut off.

But if I remove `overflow:hidden` then `.row-2` would be initially visible which is wrong.

I could have another element below my `.bar` with some specific `background-color` and `z-index` higher than `.row` but lower than those dropdowns I mentioned but it's not real solution and it's actually impossible because below `.bar` I have some other elements.

Anyway, solution for this doesn't have to use those translateY methods. It could be something else, but hopefully without JS.

```css
.bar {
  background: #7187A2;
  color: #35495F;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.row {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#switch:checked ~ .bar .row-1,
#switch:checked ~ .bar .row-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-80px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-80px);
}
body {
  padding-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="switch">
<label for="switch">Click here</label>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="row row-1">This is row number 1</div>
  <div class="row row-2">And that's 2nd row</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some code to your question. It is not clear to understand the problem without code. If you can make a fiddle of the same then it will be more helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: @NileshMahajan you might have missed the [link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvwc27u7/).

Comment: So the height of `.bar` needs to change, depending on how much space the visible row requires?

Comment: @NileshMahajan There's a link to jsfiddle but I've also added code snippet in here as well.

Comment: @PawelLudwiczak: Aaah I missed that link.. will look into it now.

Comment: @janfoeh the height of bar and row are always the same.

Comment: Ah, _now_ I know what you mean - it's about the dropdown elements in their extended state. But they are not affected by `overflow: hidden`? [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/vvwc27u7/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You can change the slide effect , and instead use a scale effect. It isn't the same, but it is pretty close:

```
.row-1 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
}
.row-2 {
    margin-top: -80px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#switch:checked ~ .bar .row-1
 {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
}

#switch:checked ~ .bar .row-2
 {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvwc27u7/2/)

The first row is collapsed above the top margin. (see the transform origin)

The second row, initially is collapsed at the bottom margin, and it expands to the full height from there.

Comment: I like it! If i won't be able to solve this problem I'd probably go with your solution, though it's not perfect, but works good :) Thanks!

Comment: Happy that it helped. Hopefully somebody will find a better solution !